# Как называется данный способ построения веб-страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, css

На [этом сайте](http://www.hiitbk.com/) очень круто реализована прокрутка, когда задний план статичен, в отличие от переднего. Наверняка есть какой-то готовый модуль для реализации этой фичи. Вот только я даже не знаю, как его гуглить.

Как это называется?

Comment: parallax - https://codyhouse.co/demo/fixed-background-effect/index.html

Comment: @soledar10 выручил, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это называется Parallax scrolling. Насчет готовых модулей не знаю.
`Вот` http://codepen.io/search/pens?q=parallax&limit=all&type=type-pens можешь посмотреть примеры на CodePen.